# avoid adding a folderish object inside another object of the same type

Tags: plone

We have a content type (lets call it, **MyFolder**) that could contain any other content type registered in the site except for **MyFolder** itself.

what's the simplest way to accomplish this?

1. registering a new workflow and setting guards?
2. removing the **Add MyFolder** permision of the content type from the object with an event at creation time?
3. filtering the content type from the list of addable content types in the object? how?
4. none of the above? how then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think than point 3 has some complexity and turnarounds because you need to revoke `Modify contrains types` permission but maybe that is not the intended behavior because that way you are restricting user to modify all the locally allowed types besides MyFolder, and finally the user could find workarounds for this limitation... for example, MyFolder -> Folder -> MyFolder

point 2 is more simple, you just revoke one permission with an event handler when a new MyFolder is created, since you are revoking the permission and disabling acquisition for that perm. there is no easy workarounds to avoid the limitation, and the user could still use the configuration of locally allowed types for every addable content type but MyFolder.

Answer (score 1):

I guess point 3 should work fine, set the "Filter content types" flag on `MyFolder` and select all others that should be addable in "Allowed content types" of `MyFolder`

Of course if you add other content types, you have to manually extend the "Allowed content types" of `MyFolder`.

Another solution could be to set the localallowedtypes on every instance of `MyFolder`using an eventhandler `zope.lifecycleevent.interfaces.IObjectCreatedEvent`.

In this event handler you can check for the parent and set the local allowed types. 
Then you have to make sure, that your "normal" user cannot modify the local allowed types by uncheck the `Modify constrain types` permission.

But also here you have to manage new content types manually.

Yet another solution:
If your are using dexterity types, there is a `TypeSettingsAdapter` (https://github.com/plone/plone.app.dexterity/blob/master/plone/app/dexterity/browser/types.py)
You can register your own adapter for your specific type.